# Possible ways to choose 6 units out of 18 units where 2 units must be together

Tags: combinations

How many different groups of 6 children can be chosen from a class of 18 children if the class contains one set of twins who must not be seperated?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 1):

Consider two cases: the twins are in the group of $6$, or not.

If the twins are in the group of $6$, then it remains to choose $4$ more children from the remaining $16$.

If the twins are not in the group of $6$, then you need to choose $6$ students from $16$.